# Prompting a Msg Box when data in an Excel cell range updates

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have searched high an low for this but cannot get it to work for my entire range.  And this is my first post, so be gentle.

I have an algorithm that analyzes the time that certain products should move from one production phase to the next.  It then provides the amount of resources needed to complete the next phase of production.

My problem is that when the resources exceed what is available I want a pop-up box to appear and warn the user; this should happen for all cells within the range.  I have gotten this to work successfully, but only when cell "S7" exceeds the value.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRng As Range

    Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SMT 2").Range("S7:S26")

    For Each mycell In myRng

        If mycell.Value >= 16 Then sVar = _
        MsgBox("Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

        If sVar = 7 Then
            Application.Undo
        End If

        Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use VBA for this? You can achieve the same with Data Validation? or do you want them to be able to override the values if they want?

Comment: I need the user to be able to enter any sub-assembly to the list.  Based on the time it takes to build it will come up with a completion time.  This will tell you what amount of resources will be in use at a given time.  This will trigger the message box.

Comment: Why use a loop? If `S7:S10` has say 17 and the user enters 17 in say `S21` then you will get 5 message boxes if the user chooses to press `Yes` this can be very annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to go through all cells or just S7 to S26?

If you want to go through S7:S26, this is the code: (Exit For was at the wrong place)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SMT 2").Range("S7:S26")

    For Each mycell In myRng
        If mycell.Value >= 16 Then 
            sVar = MsgBox("Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")
            If sVar = 7 Then
                Application.Undo
                Exit For
            End If
        End if
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OK if I can just add one more question.  When I run this it works, except that if there is already a cell in the range "S7:S26" that exceeds a value of 16 it will prompt the msg box even if the cell that corresponds with the material I am putting in does not exceed 16 (i.e., product goes in cell A11 and cell S11 returns 10 [does not exceed resource limits], but because cell S7 shows 17 [exceeding resource limits] the message box will appear).  Again any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop. You can use `Intersect` to check if any cell in the range `Range("A7:A26")` is changed. Also note, the below code doesn't cater to scenario where then user pastes values `>16` in that range.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set myRng = Range("A7:A26")

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, myRng) Is Nothing Then
        lRow = Target.Row

        If Range("S" & lRow).Value >= 16 Then sVar = _
        MsgBox("Will Enough Pre-Wave Resources be Available?", 4, "Attention!")

        If sVar = 7 Then Application.Undo
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth, that second answer didn't work.  That was only for manual inputs to range S7:S26.

Comment: I tested the above code and it worked. Are you pasting the code in the `Sheets("SMT 2")` sheet code area?

Comment: I mean it worked functionally, but it's not what I'm looking for.  When I enter a sub-assembly and the information updates, the msg box will not come up based on the input from another cell.  I have to manually put in a number into the range S7:S26.

Comment: How are the values populating in range `S7:S26`? Via a formula?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to correspond to the row in which I populate the subassembly.  So if I update A7, then S7 updates.  And if S7 exceeds 16, then I want the msg box to appear.

Comment: Post updated. Try it now... You might have to refresh the page

Comment: Fantastic!  That is Perfect!  Thanks Siddharth!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Wish you would have specified that the values in Col S were being populated by a formula based on Col A. I would have given the exact solution earlier :)